# Modify Pandas Multi-Index DataFrame Values using Pandas Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

We have a multi-index DataFrame `df`

```
            0  1  2
Name Stock         
Tom  AAPL   0  0  0
     GOOG   0  0  0
     NFLX   0  0  0
John AAPL   0  0  0
     GOOG   0  0  0
     NFLX   0  0  0
```

and a Series `s`

```
AAPL    99
NFLX    11
dtype: int64
```

**Question:** How can we set the values in column `2` of the dataframe `df` using values from the series `s`?

In other words, only the values for index `('Tom', 'AAPL')` and `('Tom', 'NFLX)` in dataframe `df` should be set to `99` and `11`, respectively. `('Tom', 'GOOG')` should remain unchanged.

**Failed Attempt**

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx['Tom', :], 2] = s
print(df)
```

```
            0  1    2
Name Stock           
Tom  AAPL   0  0  NaN
     GOOG   0  0  NaN
     NFLX   0  0  NaN
John AAPL   0  0  0.0
     GOOG   0  0  0.0
     NFLX   0  0  0.0
```

**Code to Reproduce Problem**

```
stocks = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'NFLX']
names = ['Tom', 'John']
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([names, stocks], names=['Name','Stock'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=midx)
for i in range(3):
    df[i] = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
print(df)

s = pd.Series([99, 11], index=['AAPL','NFLX'])
print('\n', s, '\n')

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx['Tom', :], 2] = s
print(df)
```

Comment: What about `John, AAPL` and `John, NFLX`, shouldn't these be changed as well?

Comment: Changes are only for `Tom`, which I attempted to specify using `df.loc[idx['Tom', :], 2] = s`

Answer (score 2):

Create `MultiIndex` in `Series` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for same index like original `df` and then set values with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = pd.Series([99, 11], index=['AAPL','NFLX'])
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Tom'], s.index])
s = s.reindex(df.index)
print(s)
Name  Stock
Tom   AAPL     99.0
      GOOG      NaN
      NFLX     11.0
John  AAPL      NaN
      GOOG      NaN
      NFLX      NaN
dtype: float64

df[2] = s.fillna(df[2])
print(df)
            0  1     2
Name Stock            
Tom  AAPL   0  0  99.0
     GOOG   0  0   0.0
     NFLX   0  0  11.0
John AAPL   0  0   0.0
     GOOG   0  0   0.0
     NFLX   0  0   0.0
```

Comment: Will this work if the original `df` has values other than `0`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx - Sure, because `df[2] = s.fillna(df[2])` replace non matched values by original

Answer (score 1):

Using [`index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with `loc`:

```
s = pd.Series(data=[99,11], index=['AAPL', 'NFLX'])
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Tom'], s.index]) # thanks Jezrael

idx1 = df.index.get_level_values('Name') == 'Tom'
idx2 = df.index.get_level_values('Stock').isin(s.index)

df.loc[idx1&idx2, 2] = s
```

**Output**

```
              0    1     2
Name Stock                
Tom  AAPL   0.0  0.0  99.0
     GOOG   0.0  0.0   0.0
     NFLX   0.0  0.0  11.0
John AAPL   0.0  0.0   0.0
     GOOG   0.0  0.0   0.0
     NFLX   0.0  0.0   0.0
```

Comment: hmmm, what about `s = pd.Series([99, 11], index=['NFLX','AAPL'])` ?

Comment: Yes you're right, need to have matching indices. Edited @jezrael

Comment: daily cap, not seen ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by setting "Name" column and using merge like below

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Tom', 'AAPL', '0', '0', '0'], ['Tom', 'GOOG', '0', '0', '0'], ['Tom', 'NFLX', '0', '0', '0'], ['John', 'AAPL', '0', '0', '0'], ['John', 'GOOG', '0', '0', '0'], ['John', 'NFLX', '0', '0', '0']], columns=('Name', 'Stock', '0', '1', '2'))
df1.set_index(["Name", "Stock"], inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['AAPL', '99'], ['NFLX', '11']], columns=('Stock', 'Value'))

df2["Name"]="Tom"
df1.merge(df2, on=["Name", "Stock"], how="left").set_index(["Name", "Stock"])
```

**Result**

```
            0  1  2 Value
Name Stock               
Tom  AAPL   0  0  0    99
     GOOG   0  0  0   NaN
     NFLX   0  0  0    11
John AAPL   0  0  0   NaN
     GOOG   0  0  0   NaN
     NFLX   0  0  0   NaN
```